# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, haml

I am working on a basic form in a Rails 4.2 app that submits a form for a review of a restaurant. However, when my test runs I get the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: click_button "Submit review"
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   Restaurant(#70225646207060) expected, got String(#70225618208620)
 # ./app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

I know there are lots of similar questions out there and I have tried many of the solutions but so far none have worked. What is this error indicating and what is the right solution?

Here is the create method from reviews_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    Review.create!(params[:review].permit(:restaurant, :presentation, :service, :atmosphere, :comment))
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

The new review form (haml), I left out other fields that are text entry :

```
  = form_for @review do |f|
    = f.label :restaurant  
    = f.collection_select(:restaurant, Restaurant.all, :id, :name)

    = f.submit "Submit review"
```

review.rb model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a param name of `restaurant`, `Review.create!` will use Review's `restaurant=` method, which expects a Restaurant object.

If you switch to using `restaurant_id` as your param, it should work.

```
# controller
Review.create!(params[:review].permit(:restaurant_id, :presentation, :service, :atmosphere, :comment))

# form
= f.collection_select(:restaurant_id, Restaurant.all, :id, :name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. However, when I make the changes you suggest I get:  ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `restaurant_id' for #<Review:0x007fbd608e8990>  Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: Does Review `belongs_to` Restaurant?

Comment: Yes, I added my Review model into my question. What else am I missing?

Comment: In a console, does `Review.last.restaurant_id` work?

Comment: Ok, that did not work. The problem was that I had not created restaurant_id in the table. Once I added that field as a reference in a new migration everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you are trying to do is following:

```
= f.select :restaurant, Restaurant.pluck(:id, :name)
```

Comment: I didn't get an error from that but the values in the drop-down in the form are only the ids. I reordered your suggestion to be (:name, :id) so the drop-down showed the correct value but I still got the AssociationTypeMismatch: error. Is there something else I should look at?

Comment: when I try that I get: undefined method `restaurant_id' for #<Review:0x007fbd5d587ee8>